# Mysql: get row with most matching columns

Tags: mysql, select

I have an user table like this:

```
Id --- Privilege1 --- Privilege2 --- Privilege3 --- Privilege4 --- Privilege-5
 1          1              0             0               1             0
 4          0              1             0               0             0
12          1              1             1               1             0
```

The `ID`contains the user ID, and `Privilege1 - Privilege5` contains the value `0` (no) or `1` (yes).

I need to get the ID of the row where most of the Privileges are `1`. In my example it should be 12, because that row has the most `1's`. How can I do this?

Comment: The database design is horrible. Next time make one column for privilege_id as a foreign key and another table for privilege levels.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `id`, (`Privilege1` + `Privilege2` + `Privilege3` + `Privilege4` + `Privilege5`) AS `priv`
FROM `table`
HAVING `priv` = MAX(`Privilege1` + `Privilege2` + `Privilege3` + `Privilege4` + `Privilege5`)
```

Comment: The query returns NULL: no result :(

Comment: I tested @Jordy, and it works fine for me with your table structure.